close userform by drag and drop on TreeView
I have a simple Userform with a single TreeView widget. There are no other widgets. The TreeView accepts Drag and Drop which is used to import a text file. After the user drops a file on the TreeView I want the Userform to close automatically. The issue I am running into is that when I try to close the userform from the DragDrop Sub another instance of Excel opens up with the full contents of the text file. The Subroutine I use to import the text file runs fine, I simply want to suppress the additional Excel instance from opening.
I have tried a few things to circumvent the behavior I'm trying to avoid. First, I made a call to "Unload Me" from the TreeView OLEDragDrop Subroutine.
Private Sub TreeView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    Dim sPath As String, sName As String
    sPath = Data.Files(1)
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add KEY:=sPath, Text:=get_file_name(sPath)
    READ_WEB_LOADS_FILE sPath
    Unload Me ' <--- this closes the userform, but still opens another instance of Excel
End Sub

Second, in the TreeView subroutine I call a public subroutine from a Module to try to close the Userform remotely. Third, from the TreeView subroutine I called a public subroutine in a Module, from the subroutine a call another subroutine using "Evaluate" to close the userform. In all cases whenever I try to close the userform after the Drag and Drop procedure, no matter how I daisy-chain the subroutine calls or where the subroutines are located (Module or Userform), I still get an additional Excel file with the contents of the text file.
Public Sub READ_WEB_LOADS_FILE(ByVal path As String)
    
    Dim ff As Long, indx As Long
    Dim contents As String
    Dim Loads_Section As Variant
    
    ' read file
    ff = FreeFile ' ........................................... get next free file number
    Open path For Input As #ff ' .............................. open file for reading
    contents = Input(LOF(ff), ff) ' ........................... read file into string variable
    Close #ff ' ............................................... close file
    
    ' parse file on line breaks
    Loads_Section = Split(contents, "BEGIN LOADS:") ' ......... split Loads Sections
    contents = "" ' ........................................... release memory
    
    ' operate on individual loads sections
    For indx = 1 To UBound(Loads_Section) ' ................... iterate over sections
        
        ' extract loads
        EXTRACT_LOADS
        
        ' build Max/Min Table
        BUILD_MAX_MIN_TABLE
        
    Next indx
    
    
    ' *** This closes the UserForm, but still opens another instance of Excel ***
    Unload UserForm1
    
    ' *** This closes the UserForm, but still opens another instance of Excel ***
    Evaluate "CLOSE_FORM"
    
End Sub

Yes, I can close the Userform by pressing the X in the upper corner. I just want to figure out how to close the Userform when the subroutine ends.
Edit 1:
Added "get_file_name" function code
Private Function get_file_name(ByVal sPath As String) As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(sPath, "\")
    get_file_name = arr(UBound(arr))
End Function


I don't see any code in what you included in your question that would open another instance of Excel. Perhaps that code exists somewhere else in your code and is getting called during the form unload?

Can you post the code behind the "get_file_name" function?

can you try setting Effect to fmDropEffectNone ?

@aphoria
It's the same effect if you were to drop a text file on an Excel Worksheet. It automatically does an import into a new Workbook. That's what is happening when I try to close the Userform after I Drag&Drop a file on it.

@tinazmu
Can you elaborate? I cannot find this property.

I don't see anything in the code you have included here that would open another instance of Excel. Do you have any code in the form Terminate sub?

@aphoria
No, I don't use the UserForm_Terminate() sub. That's what I'm saying. I have no code that would do this. It seems like some default setting in Excel where if you were to Drag&Drop a text file on a Worksheet it will trigger an import event. It displays this same behavior when I try to close the Userform  in a single action when I import the text data into the worksheet. It then automatically does it's own text file import into a new instance of Excel. I want to know how to suppress this event. I cannot even find where or how this action gets triggered.

I cannot replicate this behavior when dropping a file on a treeview.
